# Assuming the order Conv2d->ReLU->BN, should the Conv2d layer have a bias parameter?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization, activation-function, relu

Should we include the bias parameter in `Conv2d` if we are going for `Conv2d` followed by `ReLU` followed by `batch norm (bn)`?

There is no need if we go for `Conv2d` followed by `bn` followed by `ReLU`, since the shift parameter of `bn` takes care of bias work.

Comment: @jww To be fair, this is in the worst case a borderline fit, as it is an algorithmic question and it does ask about a developpement choice. It litterally checks out two of the four bullet points at the begining of the "what topics can I ask about." page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the order is `conv2d -> ReLU -> BatchNorm`, then having a `bias` parameter in the convolution can help. To show that, let's assume that there is a bias in the convolution layer, and let's compare what happens with both of the orders you mention in the question. The idea is to see whether the bias is useful for each case.

Let's consider a single pixel from one of the convolution's output layers, and assume that `x_1, ..., x_k` are the corresponding inputs (in vectorised form) from the batch (batch size == `k`). We can write the convolution as

```
Wx+b #with W the convolution weights, b the bias
```

As you said in the question, when the order is `conv2d-> BN -> ReLu`, then the bias is not useful because all it does to the distribution of the `Wx` is shift it by `b`, and this is cancelled out by the immediate BN layer:

```
(Wx_i - mu)/sigma  ==> becomes (Wx_i + b - mu - b)/sigma i.e. no changes.
```

However, if you use the other order, *i.e*

```
BN(ReLU(Wx+b))
```

then `ReLU` will map some of the `Wx_i+b` to `0`· As a consequence, the mean will look like this:

```
(1/k)(0+...+0+ SUM_s (Wx_s+b))=some_term + b/k
```

and the `std` will look like

```
const*((0-some_term-b/k)^2 + ... + (Wx_i+b - some_term -b/k)^2 +...))
```

and as you can see from expanding those therms that depend on non-zero `Wx_i+b`:

```
(Wx_i+b - some_term - b/k)^2 = some_other_term + some_factor * W * b/k * x_i
```

which means that the result will depend on `b` in a ***multiplicative*** manner. As a result, its absence can't just be compensated by the shift component of the BN layer (noted `beta` in most implementation and papers). That is why having a bias term when using this order is not useless.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot :). Just a question, in the 1st case: `conv2d-> BN -> ReLu`, would the bias have an influence at *inference time* when the mean and std is not based on the current stats? In this situation we would have `(Wx_i + b - mu_{training})/sigma_{training}`.  My gut feeling tells me this may cause wrong/ unexpected results if the biases have not been disabled nor initialised to 0.